# How to resolve relative paths in css with Brunch?

Tags: css, url, brunch, build-tools, css-import

For example, I use 3rd party library that has style definition like `background: url(img/blue.png)` in it's css file. When Brunch concatenates all files together and puts output file to public folder, then this URL doesn't work anymore because it still has relative path. And browser gets 404 error while trying to load this image. Is there any plugin or something like that to replace relative paths in stylesheet's url()/import() directives automatically?

Comment: you can change it to `url(/img/blue.jpg)`

Comment: you can write your own function/module in brunch to carry about the urls

Comment: is it really so rare case that such plugin is still missing?

Comment: I don't entirely understand your problem. It's true that Brunch does not automatically convert relative paths. But you can just assign the adequate value (of the image in the public folder) in the first place.